# HTML Body width exceeds monitor width without any styling or content?

Tags: html, width, screen, document

See the following picture:

[image: What the inspector shows]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Ep9.jpg

This is absolutely terrible, since I require a pixel accurate value for the document with. Unfortunately ALL values (document.body.scrollWidth, document.body.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.offsetWidth) Show the wrong value. I have no Idea what's going on. There is no styling and no content on the site. My screen is full HD (1920)

EDIT: The bug seems to be browser specific. While opera says ~2170, chrome correctly says 1920! What's going on with opera ?

Comment: May I ask you why you need the pixel accurate value for the document width?

Comment: Because I'm working with canvas and WebGL and If I don't know the exact width of the canvas and therefore the body, the image will get blurry.

Comment: All I know is that `$(window).width()` in jQuery is utterly reliable...